# How to execute an alias, encapsulated in another source file?

Tags: alias, tcsh, csh

For instance

`~/.cshrc`:

`alias job_start 'cd $PROJ_DIR && source .env/bin/activate.csh && rehash && job_run'`

`$PROJ_DIR/.env/bin/activate.csh`:

```
alias job_run '(cd $PROJ_DIR/builds; sh run.sh)'
```

after calling job_start:

```
% job_start                                                                                                                                                                                                  [4/36]
job_run: Command not found.
```

But aliases updates after calling `job_start` -> `job_run` appears.

Manually calling `job_run` will proceed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have your alias source a script, rather than trying to have it execute things directly:

```
alias job_start 'cd $PROJ_DIR && source ~/bin/job_start'
```

where `~/bin/job_start` looks like this:

```
source .env/bin/activate.csh
rehash
job_run
```

Alternatively, if the changes to the enviroment don't need to be retained, you could just have the alias execute `~/bin/job_start`.

Also, if `~/bin` is in your path, renaming `~/bin/job_start` script to something else might be appropriate :-)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your advice :D. You didn't ask the question and didn't write a solution either.

Comment: Yes I did? Your problem is that the alias tries to figure out what to do when the alias is defined. That doesn't work for things that aren't defined yet when the alias is created. The solution to that is that you should do something which is guaranteed to be possible (i.e., source a different script) which can then do whatever is needed (in your case, do what your alias currently tries to do)

Comment: `The solution to that is that you should do something which is guaranteed to be possible (i.e., source a different script) which can then do whatever is needed (in your case, do what your alias currently tries to do)` -> Isn't that what I've did already by calling `source activate.csh`, which contains alias of a script, that I want to be executed?

Comment: yes, but the new alias isn't created in a way that makes it visible for the old alias. If you run it in a separate script (which gets sourced), then it is. *That* is why you need to source rather than directly add things in your alias. This is also what the official tcsh website [suggests](http://www.tcsh.org/TipsAndTricks) (TIP#1) for your problem.